# Bootstrap multiselect: close dropdown for each checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, multi-select

I have used Bootstrap multiselect created by davidstutz.

I have enabled multiselection, and select all checkbox also, but when I selecting checkbox it gets selected, but not dropdown is not closing as like single selection. This is a very specific requirement for me.

How can I close the dropdown for each option selection as like normal select box?

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select" 
        multiselect-dropdown="reportListDropdown" ng-model="reports.reportList"
        ng-options="replist.id as replist.name for replist in reports.reportListArr">
</select>
```

Answer:

```
 272:  if (this.options.multiple) {
 273:      // Simply select additional option.
 274:      $option.prop('selected', true);
+275:      this.$button.click();
       }
```

I have added `this.$button.click();` code in the 275 th row and as well as in the else part of bootstrap-multiselect.js and it just worked fine, but editing the core file is not a genuine solution, so does anybody know a clean way to handle this with property or options level?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Could we see some code?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have used the following directive to make it work this plugin in angularjs - [bootstrap multiselect angular directive](https://gist.github.com/dancras/5191040)

Answer (score 3):

To **close the Bootstrap MultiSelector** from within jQuery, I found that **a simple click on any other object** would close it using the native functionality. Thus, this worked:

```
$(document).click();
```

Here is an example of **iterating over the checked MultiSelect items and then closing** the MultiSelect:

```
$('#foo').on("change", '[name="bar\\[\\]"]', function() {

    $('[name="bar\\[\\]"]:checked').each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).val() );
    });

    $(document).click(); // This closes the MultiSelector
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out another solution for this (better in my opinion :D )
I noticed that when drop-down is opened class named 'open' is appended to the div container. So, to close drop-down just remove the class. You can do it like this:

```
$('#dropdownSelector').multiselect({
        buttonContainer: '<div id="dropdownContainer"/>',
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            $('#dropdownContainer').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
        this.$container.removeClass('open');
    }
});
```